# display inline doesnt work correctly

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

the image is placed behind the input element and not next (with small margins).

This is how it works now: [Inline doesnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM8xM.jpg)

I do not get to do that every item be one followed the other without overlap

CSS

```
.mfc-number-step {
  margin: 10px;
  input {
    width: 202;
    height: 41px;
  }
}

.mfc-number-step__status--error {
    border-color: red;
    background: #fff3f2;
}

.mfc-number-step__status--disabled {
    color: #8b8b8b;
}

.mfc-number-step__button {
    width: 41px;
    height: 41px;
}

input, img {
    display: inline;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="mfc-number-step">
  <input type="text" ng-class="{'mfc-number-step__status--error' : mfcNumberStepStatusError === 'true' , '.mfc-number-step__status--disabled' : mfcNumberStepStatusDisabled === 'true'}" ng-disabled="mfcNumberStepStatusDisabled === 'true'" value="{{mfcNumberStepUnitMeasure}}" class="mfc-number-step__input"/>
  <img src="{{mfcNumberStepSubtractIcon}}" class="mfc-number-step__button"/>
  <img src="{{mfcNumberStepAddIcon}}" class="mfc-number-step__button"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First at all you should use **ng-src** instead of **src** attribute inside you img tags if you want load images with the curly brackets.

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Are you using sass? Because in normal css you cant nest css classes like you did in your .mfc-number-step.

Comment: true, is with **ng-src** and yes i am using **sass**. This is the problem?

Comment: it could be the problem i cant debug your output in the browser so you have to try it

Comment: you can also try to add the width and height attribute to your img tags with the value 41

Answer (score 0):

To get it working properly, use inline-block:

```
input, img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;/* this will do the trick */
    /* make sure to give them same height + line-height + padding */
}
```

Note: keep no-spacing between the HTML tags for the inline-block to work correctly, like this:

```
<input type="text" value="sample text"/><img src="/image/myimage.jpg"/><img src="/image/myimage.jpg"/>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zvwe5g8j/)

Comment: I've tried and it does not work either. thanks for your response